# Allow Impersonation via Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

The scenario I am trying to solve is how to allow a Freelancer to login to a third party helpdesk app that only allows for authentication via Facebook.

Creating a new user on the external app is not an option due to "per account" subscription costs, but the client also does not want to allow their Freelancer to know their Facebook password, so I'm trying to conceptualize a way to middleman / proxy a login and allow the Freelancer to not login to Facebook, but only the external application impersonating the client.

Ideally they wouldn't even need to provide their password to the application, instead authorizing the app to log in on their behalf if that makes sense?

No development has started yet so language does not really matter so much as seamlessness.

Comment: There is no way.

Comment: The only thing we can realistically be talking about here would be "impersonating" a Facebook _Page_; because if your client used their personal profile to conduct that kind of business operations, they would be doing it terribly wrong to begin with. And for a page admin to grant your app permission to act on behalf of the page, is what page access tokens are for.

Comment: There is no way to capture a User Access Token, and then reuse it to authenticate against the external app for a period of time? I only need to authenticate against the external apps API which requests a Facebook token.